# Unit test Presenter's business logic

Tags: java, android, unit-testing

I'm trying to unit test the code of my `Presenter`. As you can see below in the code I'm making a Retrofit request and if the response is successful I call a method from the `View`.

Code of my Presenter I want to test :

```
@Override
public void onLoadChatrooms(String accountId, String pageNum) {
    getChatroomsService.getChatrooms(apiToken, createRequestBodyForGetChatroomsRequest(accountId, pageNum))
            .enqueue(new Callback<GetChatroomsServiceResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<GetChatroomsServiceResponse> call, Response<GetChatroomsServiceResponse> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        view.showData(Arrays.asList(response.body().getChatRoomsArray()));
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<GetChatroomsServiceResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
}
```

And here is the test I wrote :

```
@Mock
private ChatMVP.View view;

@Mock
private GetChatroomsService getChatroomsService;

@Mock
private RequestBody requestBody;

@Mock
private Call<GetChatroomsServiceResponse> call;

@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<Callback<GetChatroomsServiceResponse>> callback;

@Mock
private List<GetChatroomsResponseNestedItem> chatroomsResponseNestedItems;

private String accountId = "14";
private String apiToken = "someToken";

private ChatPresenter chatPresenter;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    chatPresenter = new ChatPresenter(view, getChatroomsService, apiToken);

}

@Test
public void onLoadChatrooms() throws Exception {
    when(getChatroomsService.getChatrooms(apiToken, requestBody))
            .thenReturn(call);

    chatPresenter.onLoadChatrooms(accountId, "0");

    verify(call).enqueue(callback.capture());
    callback.getValue().onResponse(call, getResponse());

    verify(view).showData(chatroomsResponseNestedItems);
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting a `NPE` for line : 
`chatPresenter.onLoadChatrooms(accountId, "0");`

The exact error message is :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at my.package.main.fragments.chat.ChatPresenter.onLoadChatrooms(ChatPresenter.java:40)
at my.package.main.fragments.chat.ChatPresenterTest.onLoadChatrooms(ChatPresenterTest.java:70)
```

where `line 40` for ChatPresenter is : `.enqueue(new Callback<GetChatroomsServiceResponse>() {`

Anyone can help with that ? I tried checking if Presenter is null and that's not the problem.

EDIT :

ChatPresenter's constructor :

```
class ChatPresenter implements ChatMVP.Presenter {

private ChatMVP.View view;
private GetChatroomsService getChatroomsService;
private String apiToken;

@Inject
ChatPresenter(ChatMVP.View view, GetChatroomsService getChatroomsService, @Named("Api-Token") String apiToken) {
    this.view = view;
    this.getChatroomsService = getChatroomsService;
    this.apiToken = apiToken;
}
```

and GetChatroomsService :

```
interface GetChatroomsService {

@POST("getchatrooms")
Call<GetChatroomsServiceResponse> getChatrooms(@Query("api_token") String apiToken, @Body RequestBody requestBody);

}
```

Comment: is `getChatroomsService` a variable or did you miss the parentheses?, and what does the constructor of `ChatPresenter`look like?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I've updated question with the code of ChatPresenter's constructor - also `getChatroomsService` is a variable

Comment: Please do yourself and your coworkers a favor and rename `getChatroomsService` to something that complies to the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

Comment: @TimothyTruckle thanks for pointing it out! You are right it is a very bad name.  I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the mocked method `getChatrooms()` in `getChatroomsService` returns a `null`. The most likely reason for this is that the parameters given in your production code do not match the parameters in your mock configuration.

I for myself use the `any*()` matcher when configuring the mocks and verify the parameters passed in by the production code explicitly which saves me from non descriptive NPEs like this.

```
@Test
public void onLoadChatrooms() throws Exception {
    when(getChatroomsService.getChatrooms(anyString(), any(RequestBody.class)))
            .thenReturn(call);

    chatPresenter.onLoadChatrooms(accountId, "0");

    verify(call).enqueue(callback.capture());
    callback.getValue().onResponse(call, getResponse());

    verify(getChatroomsService).getChatrooms(apiToken,requestBody);
    verify(view).showData(chatroomsResponseNestedItems);
}
```

Comment: wow that was a good catch!!Thanks a lot! I'm just starting out with unit testing and the use of `any*()` is still unclear to me. For example I tried before adding `anyString()` for accountId and pageNum vars (when calling  `onLoadChatrooms()` ) but I was getting some errors that I can't remember right now.

Comment: @Mes: *"wow that was a good catch!!Thanks a lot! I'm just starting out with unit testing"* I ran into the same problems on my start... ;o) - *"I tried before adding anyString() [...] but I was getting some errors that I can't remember right now."* Mockito wants you to be strict, either use matchers or (mock) objects, you cannot mix in the parameter list.